# ADMob Native SwiftUI - Load nib in bundle

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob, bundle

I tried to connect a native AdMob to my swiftui project. I followed the google documentation to the letter but my compiler displays this error

> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/.../' with name
> 'NativeAdView'

I've searched everywhere and I can't find any explanation. If someone could help me I'm interested !

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
      NativeAdView(nativeAdViewModel: viewModel)
    }
}


struct NativeAdView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = GADNativeAdView

    @ObservedObject var nativeAdViewModel: AdViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GADNativeAdView {
     // Link the outlets to the views in the GADNativeAdView.
        return
            Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
                "NativeAdView",
                owner: nil,
                options: nil)?.first as! GADNativeAdView
        
//        return GADNativeAdView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ nativeAdView: GADNativeAdView, context: Context) {
        
        guard let nativeAd = nativeAdViewModel.nativeAd else { return }

        // Work with your native ad.
        nativeAdView.mediaView?.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent

    }
}
```

I tried to change the GADNativeAdView and it'll work. I mean the problem come from the `return bundle.main.loadNibNamed(...)` but I can't find the right way to do it.

Comment: Running into the same problem here as well!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Xib file (call it `NativeAdView`) & set its class to `GADNativeAdView`. You will also need to associate the outlets with each property of `GADNativeAdView`.

[image: Outlets in Xib file]

See an example here - https://github.com/sakurabird/iOS-Admob-SwiftUI-example